# how to group list into the list of lists based on several conditions?

Tags: python

I am making an automation between Zoho Books and HelloCash Online Cassa System.
This automation is going to automatically book invoices, bills, expenses, as well as transactions between accounts.

I am stuck with the following problem:

I have the lists which I need to group in nested lists based on 3 same elements and one different element.

Indexes of the same elements are always `x[0], x[3], x[4]`

Index of different element id always `x[1]`

Example of the list of lists (**2d array**):

```
[['111127', '20 USt (20%)', '-29.5', '-185.54', '0'],
['111127', '20 USt (20%)', '-29.5', '-185.54', '0'],
['111127', '10 USt (10%)', '-0.77', '-185.54', '0'],
['111127', '10 USt (10%)', '-0.77', '-185.54', '0']]
```

To group based on three same fields I use **itertools groupby** function:

```
non_linear_list_grouped_bills = [
    list(v) for i, v in groupby(
        sorted(
            non_linear_list_bills,
            key = lambda x: (str(x[0]),str(x[3]),str(x[4]))
            ),
        lambda x: (str(x[0]),str(x[3]),str(x[4])))
    ]
```

But I can't get how to ensure that in each list has a different value in **x[1]**? In other words, three elements are the same and one is different

The lists of nested lists are supposed to form **2d array** and look as **follows**:

```
[['111127', '20 USt (20%)', '-29.5', '-185.54', '0'],
['111127', '10 USt (10%)', '-0.77', '-185.54', '0']],

[['111127', '20 USt (20%)', '-29.5', '-185.54', '0'],
['111127', '10 USt (10%)', '-0.77', '-185.54', '0']]
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: (1) Does `x[4]` exist? (2) `x[0] = x[1]` is True

Comment: (1) x[4] exists
(2) x[0]!= x[1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometime, we group same thing together, so you use groupby and key is x[0], x[3] and x[4].

Before groupby you sorted the list, it is not necessary, by default, groupby will do the sort first.

Now you want group by different item, I think no one can tell which items should be grouped together.

You have better create another field, like x[5], to tell what group it is. So you can groupby them with key x[5].

Comment: Thank you. Decided to use this method.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something like this ,

```
l1=[['111127', '20 USt (20%)', '-29.5', '-185.54', '0'],
['111127', '20 USt (20%)', '-29.5', '-185.54', '0'],
['111127', '10 USt (10%)', '-0.77', '-185.54', '0'],
['111127', '10 USt (10%)', '-0.77', '-185.54', '0']]
def sepk(l1):
    l2=[]
    l3=[]
    for i in l1:
        if i in l2:
            l3.append(i)
        else:
            l2.append(i)
    return l2,l3

print(sepk(l1))
```

output:

```
[['111127', '20 USt (20%)', '-29.5', '-185.54', '0'], ['111127', '10 USt (10%)', '-0.77', '-185.54', '0']]
 [['111127', '20 USt (20%)', '-29.5', '-185.54', '0'], ['111127', '10 USt (10%)', '-0.77', '-185.54', '0']]
```

give a comment if i am wrong!

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked for me:

```py
from itertools import groupby

inList = [
['111127', '20 USt (20%)', '-29.5', '-185.54', '0'],
['111127', '20 USt (20%)', '-29.5', '-185.54', '0'], 
['111127', '10 USt (10%)', '-0.77', '-185.54', '0'], 
['111127', '10 USt (10%)', '-0.77', '-185.54', '0']]

tmp =[(k, list(v)) 
  for k, v in groupby(sorted(inList, 
      key = lambda x: (str(x[0]),str(x[3]),str(x[4]))),
    lambda x: (str(x[0]),str(x[1]),str(x[3]),str(x[4])))]
```

`tmp` has all different keys possible:

```py
[(('111127', '20 USt (20%)', '-185.54', '0'),
  [['111127', '20 USt (20%)', '-29.5', '-185.54', '0'],
   ['111127', '20 USt (20%)', '-29.5', '-185.54', '0']]),
 (('111127', '10 USt (10%)', '-185.54', '0'),
  [['111127', '10 USt (10%)', '-0.77', '-185.54', '0'],
   ['111127', '10 USt (10%)', '-0.77', '-185.54', '0']])]
```

---

Then

```py
listOfKeys = [(key, value) for key, value in tmp]
tmp2 = [(k, list(v)) 
  for k, v in groupby(listOfKeys, 
    lambda key: (key[0][0], key[0][2], key[0][3]))]
```

`tmp2` groups the keys that are similar (have same `x[0]`, `x[3]` and `x[4]`) and is as follow:

```py
[(('111127', '-185.54', '0'),
  [(('111127', '20 USt (20%)', '-185.54', '0'),
    [['111127', '20 USt (20%)', '-29.5', '-185.54', '0'],
     ['111127', '20 USt (20%)', '-29.5', '-185.54', '0']]),
   (('111127', '10 USt (10%)', '-185.54', '0'),
    [['111127', '10 USt (10%)', '-0.77', '-185.54', '0'],
     ['111127', '10 USt (10%)', '-0.77', '-185.54', '0']])])]
```

---

Finally, `outList` gives you what you wanted (according to my understanding)

```py
outList = []
for key, subKeys in tmp2:
  start = len(outList)
  for k, elements in subKeys:
    for idx, element in enumerate(elements):
      index = start + idx
      if (index >= len(outList)):
        outList.append([element])
      else :
        outList[index].append(element)
```

the result is as desired

```py
[[['111127', '20 USt (20%)', '-29.5', '-185.54', '0'],
  ['111127', '10 USt (10%)', '-0.77', '-185.54', '0']],
 [['111127', '20 USt (20%)', '-29.5', '-185.54', '0'],
  ['111127', '10 USt (10%)', '-0.77', '-185.54', '0']]]
```

---

You can play around with this [Google Colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1dJtIU0-3tDmf0Fle1cHcaN29jpGJUQpJ?usp=sharing) where I tried everything